How do you write the electron configuration using gerade and ungerade notations?
My textbook shows the higher energy bonding and antibonding orbitals, and starts naming them from $1\sigma_\mathrm u.$
I don't think this is correct and it's really confusing me. What can I write if a question asks me to write the electronic configuration for something like $\ce{O2}$ using gerade and ungerade notations?

This notation is usually used for the electronic states of homonuclear diatomic, or linear molecules which belong to the $D_{\infty h}$ symmetry group. I am afraid that you need to learn a bit of group theory and symmetry to understand the notation. You would study it further into your course of Physical Chemistry. The S,P,D,... notation for atomic orbitals and atomic terms is also a symmetry notation.

I don't think you have to know it, maybe you won't have to ever :)

Symmetry: Back to Basics
Gerade parity (German for even, symbolised as $g$) and ungerade parity (uneven, symbolised as $u$) refers to the symmetry of an object. They are used to denote whether an object follows the inversion symmetry operation.
A symmetry operation is an action (moving, rotating, reflecting, anything; we call these actions transformations) that you do on an object but it results in no apparent change to the object. It is as if nothing happened! This is symmetry.
The operation we need to understand for now is the inversion operation. If we did this operation on a molecule and find that it looks the same or as if nothing happened, then the molecule is said to possess a centre of symmetry. (Check out symotter.org to help you visualise this operation). Mathematically, consider all the points that make up the object. Take a general point $(x,y)$ in the Cartesian plane. When the inversion operation acts on it, the new point is $(-x,-y)$.

Symmetry in Molecular Orbitals
$\ce{O2}$ has an inversion centre. It is a point lying midway between an imaginary line joining the centres of each oxygen atom. Now, we have a symmetric object - oxygen. Let's see how symmetric their molecular orbitals are?
Before that let's make this answer easier to understand with these points:

The molecular orbital theory is based on constructive and destructive overlapping of orbitals.
Consider the point a in the image below (left). It is related a point on the orbital wavefunction with a positive amplitude. I will call this property "blue" for now.
Similarly, point c (image on the right) has property "red" as it is related to a point with negative amplitude on the orbital wavefunction.

1) $\sigma$ Orbitals
$\sigma$ bonding orbital: In the image below (left), the molecular orbital along with the $\ce{O2}$ molecule is placed on the Cartesian plane. The inversion centre happens to be the origin of the plane. Consider an arbitrary point a which on inversion is transformed to point b. Now, both a and b belong to the same property - "blue".
Since this is true for any random point on the orbital we can now conclude: the $\sigma$ orbital of $\ce{O2}$ is symmetric (gerade) with respect to the inversion operation. Hence it will take on the label $\sigma_g$.
$\sigma^*$ antibonding orbital: You will find that there the point c with a "blue" property gets transformed to a "red" one (point d). When there is a change in this property for at least one point, we say that this molecular orbital is antisymmetric with respect to the inversion operation.
Hence, the $\sigma^*$ antibonding orbital will be ungerade and can be denoted by $\sigma_u ^*$.

2) $\pi$ Orbitals
Now, apply the inversion operation on the $\pi$ and $\pi^*$ orbitals. Here, you will find that the bonding orbital is antisymmetric (so, $\pi_u$) and the antibonding orbital is symmetric (so, $\pi_g$).



If you are considering the oxygen molecule, you should also consider the $\pi$ orbitals. There are $\pi_g$ and $\pi_u$ orbitals.

@PAEP Indeed, I will edit my answer later to include it (was exhausted last night lol).
